# jquery get text of the parent li by their child li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how i can get "Goods" when i click under "Goods" link "Restricted","Open" similarly when how i can get "Services" when i click under "Services" link "Restricted","Open" similarly,thanks in advance

*JavaScript:*

```
$('.goodsLink li a').click(function(){

    alert( $('#nav li ul li  a').html());
    return false;
});
```

*HTML:*

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Create a New Tender</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>+</strong> Goods</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>-</strong>&nbspSingle</a>

                        <ul class="goodsLink">
                            <li><a href="link.html"> -   Restricted</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="link2.html"> -   Open</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>-</strong>&nbspFramework</a>

                        <ul class="goodsLink">
                            <li><a href="link3.html"> -   Restricted</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="link4.html"> -   Open</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>+</strong> Services</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>-</strong>&nbspSingle</a>

                        <ul class="servicesLink">
                            <li><a href="link5.html"> -   Restricted</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="link6.html"> -   Open</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>-</strong>&nbspFramework</a>

                        <ul class="servicesLink">
                            <li><a href="link7.html"> -   Restricted</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="link8.html"> -   Open</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How about jquery's function `.parent()`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ can also help in the event you need to drill up an unknown amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$('.goodsLink li a').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).parents('li:contains("+")').children("a:first").text());
    return false;
});
```

But the best way should be for you to use a class or tribute to better identify the element you want to find. That way you cold replace the `:contains("+")` with a `.topParent`

She this examples:

[example with contains](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7T8fm/)

[example with class](http://fiddle.jshell.net/N8U2c/2/)